# Dropshadow on Bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to add a drop-shadow to the top floating navbar in Twitter Bootstrap

Here's my site:
http://www.japaneselanguagefriend.com/application/home.php

I believe this is the correct area in the bootstrap.min.css to target the drop shadow?
.navbar-inner

```
 .navbar-inner{min-height:45px;padding-left:25px;padding-right:25px;background-color:#fafafa;background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,
 #f89406, #fbb450);background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f89406),
 to(#fbb450));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f89406,
#fbb450);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f2f2f2);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f89406, #fbb450);background-repeat:repeat-x;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff',
 endColorstr='#fff2f2f2', GradientType=0);border:1px solid
 #d4d4d4;-webkit-border-radius:155px;-moz-border-radius:155px;border-radius:155px;-webkit-box-shadow:155
 155px 155px rgba(345, 5, 5, 5);-moz-box-shadow:515 155px 155px
 rgba(345, 0, 0, 5);box-shadow:155 155px 45px rgba(0, 0, 0,
 5);*zoom:1;}.navbar-inner:before,.navbar-inner:after{display:table;content:"";line-height:5;}
```

I then preceded to adjust the mox-box-shadow and webkit-box-shadow numbers accordingly.  I still didn't see a change.  So then I raised the numbers really high, above the 100s just to see if anything is actually changing, and still no effect or drop shadow, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? thanks!

Comment: It's line 652 in bootstrap.min.css that affects that area. Try changing things there.

Comment: It would be the best if you provide an answer with an explanation what actually did the trick.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov Sure thing, I will post it when I get home!

Comment: @AoiHana but you didn't! :)